# Recyclerview multiple viewtype causes first row item expanded unexpectedly

Tags: android-recyclerview

I want to make something like this [image]

so I am using a recyclerview which has two viewtype ( for the first item I am using one kind of viewholder and rest of item I am using another viewholder).

But on my device, it is showing like this 
[image]

[image]

For the first viewholder I am using this layout file

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

<de.hdodenhof.circleimageview.CircleImageView
    android:id="@+id/attach_circle_imageview"
    android:layout_width="80dp"
    android:layout_height="80dp"
    android:src="@drawable/attach_photo"
    app:civ_border_color="#607D8A"
    app:civ_border_width="1dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="14dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="14dp"/>
```

and for others, I am using this layout file

```
<android.support.v7.widget.CardView
    android:layout_width="90dp"
    android:layout_height="90dp"
android:layout_marginLeft="14dp"
android:layout_marginBottom="14dp"
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
app:cardCornerRadius="10dp">


<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout

    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">


<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/gallary_iv"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:scaleType="centerCrop"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />


<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/white_bg_iv"
    android:layout_width="30dp"
    android:layout_height="30dp"
    android:background="@drawable/pic_photo_number_bg"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/gallary_iv"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@+id/gallary_iv"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/gallary_iv"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/gallary_iv" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/pic_count_tv"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="1"
    android:textSize="16sp"
    android:textColor="#506876"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/white_bg_iv"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/white_bg_iv"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/white_bg_iv"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@id/white_bg_iv"/>


</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

In the first-row pictures height is expanded unexpectedly, how can I solve this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

set the first viewholder layout

```
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
```

change to

```
 android:layout_width="90dp"
 android:layout_height="90dp"
```

Comment: Thank you brother, I have forgotten this matter